# React Native - Sending information so as to receive a response for simple login screen but receiving JSON parse error instead

Tags: android, json, react-native, authentication

I have tried several times to send the data and receive a response, but it does not seem to be sending the data put in by the user. I have tried going about this in several ways,I will share the code for the last two. 
**ONE**

```
state = {
    phoneNo: '',
    pin: '', 
    isLoggingIn: false, 
    message: ''
  }

  _userLogin = () => {
     console.log("userLogin");
    this.setState({isLoggingIn: true, message:''});

    var params = {
      phoneNo: this.state.phoneNo,
      pin: this.state.pin

    };



        var proceed = false;
        fetch("https://"+"<url>", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(params)
            })
            .then(
              (response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status == 200) {

                    proceed = true;
                   }
                else {


                    this.setState({ message: response.message });
                    console.log(message); }
            })
            .then(() => {
                this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })
                if (proceed) this.props.onLoginPress();

            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err.message); 

        this.setState({ message: err.message });
        this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })
      });
    }
```

**Two**
The only difference here is how I am handling the response so I will only add that section. I thought that the issue might be due to syntax at this point.

```
.then(function(response){ 
 return response.json();   
 })
.then(function(data){ 
 console.log(data)
```

I have been through various tutorials, github and stackoverflow pages addressing the issue but I seem to be missing something. I keep getting a JSON parse error and I am convinced that perhaps the data is never being sent to the url because I get the error regardless of user input.

Both input fields have a ref and the button points to the user login function.

```
       <TextInput 
        ref = {component => this._pin = component}
        placeholder="pin" 
        onChangeText = {(pin) => this.setState({pin})}
        secureTextEntry = {true}
        onSubmitEditing={this._userLogin}

        />

        <TouchableOpacity 
         onPress={this._userLogin}
         title = "Submit"
         disabled={this.state.isLoggingIn||!this.state.phoneNo||!this.state.pin}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}>Sign In</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AlainIb was very helpful and this helped contribute to what worked in the end.  Using form data seemed to assist with the JSON Parse error. Hope this helps anyone else who is having any troubles.

```
    state = {
    message: ''
  }

_processResponse = (response) =>{
    const statusCode = response.status;
      console.log("resp", response); 
  const data = response.json();
  console.log("data", data); 
  return Promise.all([statusCode, data]).then(res => {
    return ({
      statusCode: res[0],    // the status code
      data: res[1]           // the data of the GET/POST returned by fetch call 
    })
  });
}

_userLogin = () => {
    console.log("userLogin");
    this.setState({isLoggingIn: true, message:''});

    var params = {
     phoneno: this.state.phoneno,
      pin: this.state.pin
    };

      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("phoneno", this.state.phoneno);
      formData.append("pin", this.state.pin);
      console.log(formData);

let data = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',

                  'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'
    },
    body: formData
}
    console.log(data);

  fetch("https://"+"url", data)
        .then(this._processResponse) 
        .then(res => {
          console.log("response of fetch",res);  
          const { statusCode, data } = res;
          if (statusCode == 200) {
             console.log("in if statement"); 
         if(data.login_success== 1){
            console.log("name to be passed", data.name);
            console.log("log in to profile");
            this.props.navigation.navigate('ProfileRoute');

         }else {
             console.log("fail"); 
             this.setState({message:"Password or Phone Number is Wrong"});
         }
          }else{
            this.setState({ message: data.message });
            console.log("data message" , data.message); 

          }
          this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })
        })
        .catch(err=> {
          console.error(err);
          this.setState({ message: err.message});
          this.setState({isLoggingIn: false})
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. 
I also get problem acceding both status code & data from fetch call, so i made "processResponse" function

```
processResponse=(response) =>{
  const statusCode = response.status;
  const data = response.json();
  return Promise.all([statusCode, data]).then(res => {
    return ({
      statusCode: res[0],    // the status code
      data: res[1]           // the data of the GET/POST returned by fetch call 
    })
  }
  );
}


_userLogin = () => {
    console.log("userLogin");
    this.setState({isLoggingIn: true, message:''});

    var params = {
      phoneNo: this.state.phoneNo,
      pin: this.state.pin
    };


    fetch("https://"+"<url>", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(params)
        })
        /*processResponse return both status and data , because when you make 
            .then((response) => response.json()) you return only data and status is removed 
        */
        .then(this.processResponse) 
        .then(res => {
          console.log("response of fetch",res);  
          const { statusCode, data } = res;
          if (statusCode > 200) {

            this.props.onLoginPress()


          }else{
            this.setState({ message: data.message });
            console.log("data message" , data.message); 

          }
          this.setState({ isLoggingIn: false })




        })
        .catch(err=> {
          console.error(err);
          this.setState({ message: err.message});
          this.setState({isLoggingIn: false})
        });

  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I tried it out. There was an issue with the function but after I removed the word function that worked fine but it says that processResponse the function is an undefined variable.

`processResponse(response){
//Code goes here 
 }`

It says that it is an undefined variable here... 

`.then(processResponse) `

I have changed it to processResponse() and processResponse(response)...the same error persists.

Comment: i think because you use it inside a `= () => {}` function. i edited the code `processResponse=(response) =>{}` and the call `this.processResponse`

Comment: I have done so. Thank you. Unfortunately, the JSON parse error still persists. In the log it says :

SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "Please"

Comment: what is the url and data you use ? you can test REST request with mozilla plugin like "httprequester"

Comment: I looked at the error and now there is a new one. I console logged params, so all the params are being set and taken. However it is not able to parse it as a string. This line seems to be the issue ` body: JSON.stringify(params)` . I am researching as to how to deal with this, I think I will try stringify the params the long way, like this `body: JSON.stringify({
   phoneno: this.state.phoneno,
    pin: this.state.pin,
  })`    I will try this and get back to you. What do you think would work?

Comment: i will be the same i think. maybe look on the service side, maybe error from it. what is the full url you use ?i can test it

Comment: It is  not server side. As I have tested the url and it works fine. Others seem to be facing a fairly similar issue. I have changed the mode from cors to no cors and vice versa. I have also worked on changing the content type...it seems to never say that it as a JSON...

Comment: Trying to use formData as well